# KDE manual proxy settings not working on Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, networking, proxy, kde-plasma

When I use System Settings in KDE on Kubuntu 19.10 to set manual proxy settings, it saves my configuration, but does not allow me to actually use the proxy.

Following this, if I try `env | grep -i proxy`, it does not show any proxy-related env varialbes being set.

When I manually set the proxy variables, I am still unable to use the proxy in my browser and using `curl`.
This is the format I have used: `export http_proxy='http://10.10.8.107:1080/'`

If I use `wget` instead of `curl`, I get the following:

```
Connecting to 10.10.8.107:1080... connected.
```

However, if I use the same proxy settings I tried setting in KDE's System Settings on Firefox, the proxy works for my browser.

The issue is that I require the proxy to be available system-wide. Any suggestions?